# How to find time format in a text?

Tags: python, time

I want to extract only time from a text with so many different formats of dates and time such as `'thursday, august 6, 2020 4:32:54 pm'`, `'25 september 2020 04:05 pm'` and `'29 april 2020 07:42'`. So I want to extract, for example, `4:32:54`, `07:42`, `04:05`. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Try dateparser: https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
times = [
    'thursday, august 6, 2020 4:32:54 pm',
    '25 september 2020 04:05 pm',
    '29 april 2020 07:42',
]

print("\n".join("".join(i for i in t.split() if ":" in i) for t in times))
```

Output:

```
4:32:54
04:05
07:42
```